# How to hide json data from network tab

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I use laravel and vue to menage some data from db, and i return json format from laravel controller to vue js. I just want to hide the response data from network tab or to mask them maybe. I didnt does this before. I mean, when i open network tab i see a request get-users?page=1 and if i double click open this urlhttp://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/get-users?page=1 witch show me all data like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Admin",
      "email": "admin@admin.com",
      "email_verified_at": null,
      "last_online_at": "2022-12-02 10:27:20",
```

is there any way to mask this data to somethink like this

```
    "data": [
    {
        success: true,
        response: null //or true  
    }
```

this is how i return users data

`return new UserResource(User::paginate($paginate));`

i want hide data from this tab

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/get-users?page=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Requests will be shown.**

This cannot be stopped, the application is making requests and this will be logged to the network tab by the browser, if there are security concenrns you should be handling this a different way. Do not send data to the client that they should not be allowed access to in the first place.

To try and ensure security run over HTTPS on the off chance to data gets intercepted, that way it will not be usable data. Most data will be provided by the user. Meaning in should not need to be hidden within the network tab.

Worst case scenario, someone physically sits at their computer and reads what is in the network tab, but this is a scenario that cant be accounted for when developing applications. You could `base64` encode data that is being sent to and from so it is less readable to anyone who should see the network tab. Here are some resources to have a look through related to the question.

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)